# Symbol Directed Graph using data from text file

Tags: java, algorithm, std, directed-graph

I'm so stuck, I would greatly appreciate some help. I'm currently learning Algorithms, but I have no idea where to start.

I was given code recently (We have only really done theory so seeing the code has scared me to my core) And I have been given the task to modify this code to take details from a text file and put it in a graph. The text file is similar to this.

```
Trout is-a fish
Fish has gills
Fish has fins
Fish is food
Fish is-an animal
```

Just a lot more in there. I am just wondering. How I would get started with this whole thing? There are a million questions I have to ask, but I feel like I could figure those out if only I knew how to assign the Vertices using the text file? The code I was supplied and have to edit is below. Any help would be great, Just a push in the right direction if you will.

(Also, What the heck is weight, in the addEdge class? I know it's the "cost" of traversing the edge, but how do I assign the weight?)

Thanks!

```
public class Graph {
    private final int MAX_VERTS = 20;
    private final int INFINITY = 1000000;
    private Vertex vertexList[]; // list of vertices
    private int adjMat[][]; // adjacency matrix
    private int nVerts; // current number of vertices
    private int nTree; // number of verts in tree
    private DistPar sPath[]; // array for shortest-path data
    private int currentVert; // current vertex
    private int startToCurrent; // distance to currentVert
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public Graph() // constructor
    {
    vertexList = new Vertex[MAX_VERTS];
    // adjacency matrix
    adjMat = new int[MAX_VERTS][MAX_VERTS];
    nVerts = 0;
    nTree = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<MAX_VERTS; j++) // set adjacency
        for(int k=0; k<MAX_VERTS; k++) // matrix
            adjMat[j][k] = INFINITY; // to infinity
    sPath = new DistPar[MAX_VERTS]; // shortest paths
    } // end constructor
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addVertex(char lab)
    {
    vertexList[nVerts++] = new Vertex(lab);
    }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addEdge(int start, int end, int weight)
    {
    adjMat[start][end] = weight; // (directed)
    }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void path() // find all shortest paths
    {
    int startTree = 0; // start at vertex 0
    vertexList[startTree].isInTree = true;
    nTree = 1; // put it in tree
    // transfer row of distances from adjMat to sPath
    for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++)
    {
        int tempDist = adjMat[startTree][j];
        sPath[j] = new DistPar(startTree, tempDist);
    }
    // until all vertices are in the tree
    while(nTree < nVerts)
    {
        int indexMin = getMin(); // get minimum from sPath
        int minDist = sPath[indexMin].distance;
        if(minDist == INFINITY) // if all infinite
        { // or in tree,
            System.out.println("There are unreachable vertices");
            break; // sPath is complete
        }
        else
        { // reset currentVert
            currentVert = indexMin; // to closest vert
            startToCurrent = sPath[indexMin].distance;
            // minimum distance from startTree is
            // to currentVert, and is startToCurrent
        }
        // put current vertex in tree
        vertexList[currentVert].isInTree = true;
        nTree++;
        adjust_sPath(); // update sPath[] array
   } // end while(nTree<nVerts)
    displayPaths(); // display sPath[] contents
    nTree = 0; // clear tree
    for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++)
        vertexList[j].isInTree = false;
    } // end path()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public int getMin() // get entry from sPath
    { // with minimum distance
    int minDist = INFINITY; // assume minimum
    int indexMin = 0;
    for(int j=1; j<nVerts; j++) // for each vertex,
    { // if it’s in tree and
        if( !vertexList[j].isInTree && // smaller than old one
            sPath[j].distance < minDist )
        {
            minDist = sPath[j].distance;
            indexMin = j; // update minimum
        }
    } // end for
    return indexMin; // return index of minimum
    } // end getMin()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void adjust_sPath()
    {
    // adjust values in shortest-path array sPath
    int column = 1; // skip starting vertex
    while(column < nVerts) // go across columns
    {
    // if this column’s vertex already in tree, skip it
    if( vertexList[column].isInTree )
    {
        column++;
        continue;
    }
    // calculate distance for one sPath entry
    // get edge from currentVert to column
    int currentToFringe = adjMat[currentVert][column];
    // add distance from start
    int startToFringe = startToCurrent + currentToFringe;
    // get distance of current sPath entry
    int sPathDist = sPath[column].distance;
    // compare distance from start with sPath entry
    if(startToFringe < sPathDist) // if shorter,
    { // update sPath
        sPath[column].parentVert = currentVert;
        sPath[column].distance = startToFringe;
    }
    column++;
    } // end while(column < nVerts)
    } // end adjust_sPath()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void displayPaths()
    {
        for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++) // display contents of sPath[]
    {
        System.out.print(vertexList[j].label + "="); // B=
        if(sPath[j].distance == INFINITY)
            System.out.print("inf"); // inf
        else
            System.out.print(sPath[j].distance); // 50
        char parent = vertexList[ sPath[j].parentVert ].label;
        System.out.print("(" + parent + ") "); // (A)
    }
        System.out.println("");
    }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class Graph
```

Comment: Only the "is a" relationships generate edges in the graph, no? The nodes, on the other hand, should contain "has a" items. Something like this: Trout --is a -> Fish(has gils, has fins) --is an-> Animal --is-> Food. However, one must be careful about the last two items. Fish is an Animal and Fish is Food actually looks like multiple inheritance, which would be somewhat ironic considering you're using Java.

Comment: I've got the understanding for how the graph would look, I've just got no idea how to translate that into java, if that makes sense?

Comment: Ignore "has a" lines until you get the "is a" relationships working. You need a data structure to map numbers to names and vice versa (most primitive example: use type `String[MAX_VERTS]`). Then whenever you see an "isa" line, like "Trout is a Fish", check whether Trout and Fish have corresponding numbers, if not add them, then `add_edge(numberForTrout, numberForFish, 1)`. Edge weights should all be 1 as far as I can see.

Comment: I am ready to help you, however this question doesn't seem to be general and help anyone else except you. So my question is: do you still need help? If so I will add an answer, otherwise I'd prefer not to waste my time if nobody needs it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do graphs is that I have a list or array of edges instead of storing that information in a matrix. I would create an inner edge class which contains two nodes, since this is a directional graph the two nodes have to be distinct from each other. You can also use the edge class instead of the DistPar class to track the shortest path. (Or you can repurpose the distPar class to fulfill the edge functionality for you).

Weights are properties given to edges. The analogy I like to use is airline routes. Imagine that there was a single airline route from New York to LA but it cost $300 to get a ticket on that plane, but, if you took a route through a connecting airport, the ticket only costs $150. In this situation, you can think of each airport as a node and the routes between the airports are the edges which connect the nodes together. The 'weight' of the nodes in this case is the price. If you're looking to get from New York to LA, at the cheapest cost possible, you would take the cheaper route even though it passes through more airports.

Weights basically shift the definition of the shortest path between any two nodes from the least amount of connecting nodes to the least weight between these two nodes. Dijkstra's Algorithm is similar to the one which you have implemented, but also takes advantage of weights, redefining the shortest path as we have above.

I hope this was helpful!